# Responsive title with different background images on each side

Tags: css

I have some CSS challenge here. To describe what I am after is challenge as well :) so hope it makes sense.

I need text title that will align in the middle of DIV container.

The title needs to have a background image that will apply to its left side and different background image that will apply to its right side.

The background behind the TITLE text must be transparent.

```
~~~~bg image1~~~~ TITLE ~~~~bg image2~~~~
```

The `width` of DIV container varies as well as the TITLE text length.

I've tried to apply content with `:before` and `:after` markup

```
h1 {margin: 0 auto;display: table;}
h1:before {content: url('image_left.png');}
h1:after {content: url('image_right.png');}
```

however this does not work for me as the width of :before and :after element equals to the width of content image and I can not figure out how to make it responsive.

Any hints appreciated :)

Comment: Can you add an image, how it should look like?

Comment: add text-align: center; to the containing div (wraps both images and text) - that should center the h1-text
Wrap both images in a div and float one left and the other right with a negative z-index. 
If you want to preserve aspect ratio on the images, you need more code..

Comment: Here is the link with images of what Iam trying to achieve[link] (http://www.evernote.com/shard/s5/sh/a8cd036c-6b71-4db0-9e4f-65193fa69eec/3d061ae7939dc0356949540a9bd65152)

Comment: Without your code its difficult to see whats actually going on - looks like you have 2 images (the icons) placed on each side of h1 - and a third element (the line) going through everything?

Comment: Have you tried giving `background-image` to the before and after, rather than `content`?

Comment: Kenneth you are right that is my approach. I did not provide the code as the solution is not working. The provided link above shows what is my goal in the last image.


Yes Mr Lister I did try that. But I can not figure out how to make before and after element to span across remaining width on left and on the right.

Comment: I've put my code on CodePen. So here it is: http://codepen.io/dc006/pen/BupmF

Comment: The solution was provided by wolfcry911 @ css-tricks and can be found here http://codepen.io/wolfcry911/pen/hilbH